# onreadystatechange not working consistently between browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

In short I'm trying to get the dimensions of any given div's background-image so I can do some fancy sprite animations with it. The code below is a simplified version but illustrates the blocking issue.

Given a div with a styled background-image, with the class "animation", the following will return the naturalWidth of the background image in FF/Safari/Chrome, but not in any IE:

```
var testarray = [];
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("animation");

console.log("testarray.length: ", testarray.length);

onload = function starttest(){
    console.log("in onload");
    console.log("testarray.length: ", testarray.length); //returns correct length in all browsers
    console.log("testarray[0].src: ", testarray[0].src); //returns filename in all browsers
    console.log("testarray[0].naturalWidth: ", testarray[0].naturalWidth); //returns 0 in IE only
}

document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    console.log("in readystatechange");
    console.log("document.readystate: ", document.readyState);
    var thing = new Image();
    testarray.push(thing);
    if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
        var bi = window.getComputedStyle(divs[0], false).backgroundImage.slice(4, -1);
        testarray[0].src = bi;
        document.body.appendChild(testarray[0]);
    }
}
```

The above is run in an embedded script below the body tag.

Why does the loaded image have no dimensions in IE? appendChild fails silently in IE as well, though works great in other browsers. I'd prefer a native JS answer over jQuery.

Comment: UM, why are you not using the onload event of the image to get the width of the image?

Comment: The image onload event fires for Chrome (haven't tried FF/Safari) and I can measure the dimensions (but I can already do that without the image onload event). However, this still doesn't work for IE.

Comment: Okay figured out why the image onload event was not firing; if it's set whatever.onload = function(){} then it doesn't work in IE, but if it's set whatever.onload = someotherfunction(); then it does fire. However I still cannot access the image dimensions from the other function...

Comment: Ugh, IE was failing where I was dynamically setting the src of the image. appendChild worked when I fixed that for IE. However, naturalWidth is set to 0 at the point of the image onload. I can query on the console and then get the naturalWidth after everything has executed. It's messy that it's not available on an event, but not disastrous for the sprite animation, since I can just show the first frame until the naturalWidth decides to populate.

Comment: `whatever.onload = someotherfunction()` should be `whatever.onload = someotherfunction;`